# Maui MediaElement is not loading the mp4 file from resources

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I doing a sample using CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement nuget package, I doing the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         x:Class="MediaElementApp.MainPage">

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Padding="30,0"
        Spacing="25">
        <toolkit:MediaElement  Source="embed://myvideo.mp4"  WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="600"
                    ShouldAutoPlay="True" ShouldMute="True" ShouldLoopPlayback="True" 
                    ShouldShowPlaybackControls="False"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

---

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
     .UseMauiApp<App>()
     .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
     .UseMauiCommunityToolkitMediaElement()
     .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
   {
      fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
      fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
   });
```

and the result is

[image]

and I have it

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hook up the `MediaFailed` event and see if it throws any error

Comment: it gives the error "Error codename: ERROR_CODE_IO_FILE_NOT_FOUND, Error message: Source error" Why?

Comment: That probably means that the video file does not end up in your app for some reason. Check your csproj file to see if there are any weird entries in there.

Comment: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/1433

Comment: just is working